# delete file of network drive in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to delete the files of network drive of server machine. WIndow Server is installed in the server machine and have it's own C, D drive and have network drive samba (\10.0.45.31)(z:)> The server machine IP is 10.0.45.22. Now how can I delete the file of network drive i.e. z drive using php. I have used following php script but does not works:

```
unlink("http://10.0.45.31/NewsHoroscope/voice/".$voice);
```

How can I do this.. need help I am stuck at here

Comment: Just Paste the extract error PHP returned

Answer (score 0):

Unlink using HTTP won't work. Try with z: :)

Comment: Can you show me how you call z:? It also can be a permission problem.

Comment: How do you call unlink ? Like that? unlink('z:/NewsHoroscope/voice/'.$voice)? If so, try this unlink('z://NewsHoroscope//voice//'.$voice) or with backslashes. I'm not sure exactly how it works, I don't use Windows for years